# Mi sistema MX Linux no reconoce php 8

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache

He tratado de buscar una solución y no la encuentro, espero me puedan ayudar a resolverlo.
En mi servidor me marca la versión 8 de PHP. Adjunto imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en mi consola me marca que tengo otra versión instalada. Adjunto imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría yo hacer que reconozca la nueva versión de PHP que es el 8?

Comment: Prueba con `update-alternatives --config php` en un terminal a ver si te sale algo

Comment: Me sale que solo tengo PHP 7.4

Comment: Accedí a la carpeta /etc/ y ya vi que tengo solo PHP 7.4, pero no entiendo por qué el servidor me marca que tengo la versión 8

Comment: lo que pasa es que la version que ve apache no siempre es la version que reconoce el sistema operativo como CLI.

Comment: a menos que no necesistes nada de php 8 para ser ejecutado desde CLI no tiene mayor importancia.